# Where to keep exception.sites when running java application using an embedded jre?

Tags: java, java-8

I dont have java INSTALLED in my machine. but i have kept the embedded jre in `c:\test\java8\.`

Now I am launching a Java application from the above jre location from cmd. Now I am getting Java Application Blocked, since my application is tried to download some files from a url.

If Java was installed, I can either add this URL in the Java control panel or can perform it programatically to do it by adding the URL in `c:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites.`

Since I am running from an embedded `JRE`, how and where can I add this exception site's URL?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What makes your JRE installed under `c:\test\java8\­` an “embedded JRE”?

Comment: @Holger Yes, its an embedded jre. So basically, if java is not "installed" then my app will relay on this jre to launch, but the problem is where will we keep exception.sites ?

Comment: So it’s still the same software, just “not installed”, whatever you connect with this phrase. So why shouldn’t it read exactly the same file?

Comment: @Holger because only while installing the path "c:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites." is automatically getting created. If i am using embedded jre, am not sure if this will be the same location for the exception list path.

Comment: So, it’s not possible to create that directory and file and check whether it will be used when present? That test would have taken less time than you’ve already spent on Stackoverflow.